# How to input a frequently-used sequence of letters

Tags: macos, microsoft-word-2007

I have a sequence of letters I use all the time and I want to create a shortcut so that I don't have to retype it every time.

The sequence is one letter in lower case - a number in red - a letter in lower case, for example:  a2b, where the "2" is in red and the "a" and "b" the same color as the rest of the text. Anybody has any ideas?

Comment: Macros are the first thing that popped to my head.

Answer (score 0):

aText is at rescue: http://www.trankynam.com/atext/

You can set macros with aText to use system wide.

Answer (score 0):

Get a keyboard with macro keys - I highly recommend any of the Logitech gaming keyboards: http://gaming.logitech.com/en-ca/gaming-keyboards?WT.ac=ps|11604|KBlistingG

I use the G19 myself and love the macro keys, and the feel of the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Another program you can use is AutoHotkey.  Basically it allows you to define a sequence of key presses or even entire paragraphs when you press a combination of keys on your keyboard together.  It saves a lot typing or cutting and pasting, depending how you use it.